# Android specify theme (dark or light) one time only for all containers in activity

Tags: android

I am using API below 29 (no dark mode).

My activity has 2 containers, each with a different background color, and I would like to change the color for each one of them based if user selected Dark or Light mode.

Container 1 - background color 1

Container 2 - background color 2

I would like to know if there is a way I could set the style for all of the containers in the activity, without having to specify each one at a time.
I only want to call setTheme ONCE, for every container in the activity.
I have 2 backgrounds, but item only applies to one background. How do I solve this problem?

```
 if (darkModeIsEnabled) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme.Dark)
    } else {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme.Light)
    }

<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FFF111</item>
    <item name="background1">#D1D1D1</item>
    <item name="background2">#C1C1C1</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FFF222</item>
    <item name="background1">#D2D2D2</item>
    <item name="background2">#C2C2C2</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. Using attrs.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<attr name="searchBarBgColor" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

And setting it in the Theme style:

```
<style name="DarkModeTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="searchBarBgColor">#D6D6D6</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">                
   <item name="searchBarBgColor">#383838</item>
</style>
```

Then setting it in the container:

> ```
>             <LinearLayout
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:textColor="?attr/searchBarBgColor"
>                 android:gravity="center"
>                 android:orientation="vertical">
> ```

Then I call it once at the beginning of the activity:

```
  @Override
    public Resources.Theme getTheme() {
        Resources.Theme theme = super.getTheme();
        if(MyApp.darkMode){
            theme.applyStyle(R.style.DarkModeTheme, true);
        }
        // you could also use a switch if you have many themes that could apply
        return theme;
    }
```